# Generated APK using Android Studio. There is No Error While Compiling. But Time, App stopped responding error comes when I run the apk

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

[image]

This Error Comes Only When A Button is clicked. Otherwise the app runs properly.
Generated APK using Android Studio. There is No Error While Compiling. But Time, App stopped responding error comes when I run the apk. The App gets installed properly. When I open it and click on the login button it crashes.

I dont know how to view the logcat if you could help viewing it.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.android.mysqldemo.MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/etUserName" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="Password"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:id="@+id/etPassword"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etUserName"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:text="Login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
    android:onClick="onLogin"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etPassword"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainAcitivity.java

```
package com.example.android.mysqldemo;

import android.support.annotation.IdRes;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText UsernameEt;
    EditText PasswordEt;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        UsernameEt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
        PasswordEt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    }

    public void onLogin(View view) {
        String username = UsernameEt.getText().toString();
        String password = PasswordEt.getText().toString();
        String type = "Login";
        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
        backgroundWorker.execute(type, username, password);
    }

}
```

BackgroundWorker.java

```
package com.example.android.mysqldemo;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

/**
 * Created by TS-20f20 on 02-01-2017.
 */

public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    BackgroundWorker (Context ctx) {
        context = ctx;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type = params[0];
        String login_url = "http://aarveecreation.in/login.php";
        if(type.equals("Login")) {
            try {
                String user_name = params['1'];
                String password = params['2'];
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name, "UTF-8")+"&"+URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
                String result = "";
                String line = "";
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null) {
                    result += line;
                 }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.mysqldemo">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Pls post the error log....

Comment: I don't know how to use the logcat. I have tk run the app using USB cable and my phone. But I don't have the required drivers. So any other way to see logcat?

Comment: we can't help you with out the error log...Any way Post your code while button on click

Comment: OK wait posting code

Comment: Added Code! Now Please help Nithinlal

Comment: @PuruT. You can connect something like Crashlitycs or Firebase Crash Report(much easier) to get the error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is this?

```
String user_name = params['1'];
String password = params['2'];
```

Should be params[n] (without ')

Also, why are you doing all by hands? Did you try to use Volley? [Watch this](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html)

Comment: Oh Ooops! What is Volley?

Comment: That Worked! Lol So small of a mistake! Thanks!

Comment: @PuruT. Volley is a Google library for WEB comunication (making POST,GET, etc requests)

Comment: Oh! Got it! Will check it out! Thanks!